# Argument of type 'true' is not assignable to parameter of type 'null | undefined'

Tags: javascript, angular

I have been this error for days and I don't know what to do. I'm a programming begginer so I try to follow a course and we are in the front end. The project is make a blog, but when the user tries to login on the blog, it supposed that the program need to return a token and the user data. The problem is when I write the second parameter (true) it gives me this error. Does anyone know how I can fix it?? Thank you very much in advance for your time :)

[image]

Comment: please dont use images. just copy the relevant code and error messages, and use the appropriate indentation and code formatting :)

Comment: also, please show the code of the method you're trying to call. it seems that the definition there is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs because you are not matching the type-definition in `_userServices.signup` to a `boolean`

Whenever you write `true` or `false` you're implicitly creating a type that can only be boolean, however in your `_userServices.signup` it expects a union type of boolean|undefined.

In your `_userServices` class, look for the definition of the _userServices.signup method and change the expected type from `boolean|undefined` to `boolean`

This would look something like this:

```js
    class MyClass {
      myMethod(foo: boolean) {}
    }
```

#### Further information:

[TypeScript Every Day Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html)

[TypeScript Union Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types)

I heartily recommend the second link as your error is specifically caused by a type mismatch with a union type.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thank you and sorry is my first question. This is the code:

```
this._userServices.signup(this.user, true).subscribe(
        (response) => {
          this.identity = response;

          console.log(this.token);
          console.log(this.identity);

 localStorage.setItem('token', this.token);
 localStorage.setItem('identity', JSON.stringify(this.identity));
```

And the error message:

error TS2345: Argument of type 'true' is not assignable to parameter of type 'null | undefined'.

54           this._userServices.signup(this.user, true).subscribe(
~~~~